# JSON Web Token only work in Laravel with Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm, eloquent, token, jwt

I am using Laravel and I want to use JSon Web Token (JWT). I download the tymon vendor. When I tried to generate the token it raise me an error said that my model is not an instance of Eloquent model. So I check the vendor code and I saw this in `EloquentUserAdapter`:

```
<?php

namespace Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EloquentUserAdapter implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new User instance
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $user
     */
    public function __construct(Model $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the user by the given key, value
     *
     * @param  mixed  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function getBy($key, $value)
    {
        return $this->user->where($key, $value)->first();
    }
}
```

My problem here is that this adapter only use **Eloquent model** injection. I am using **Doctrine** models. So my questions are:

1. Is possible to change this adapter to return new model (my doctrine
   model). I asking because I am new in PHP and Laravel and I saw that
   ***EloquentUserAdapter*** is used in other places in the vendor.
2. If I create a new Adapter I think that I have to return a Eloquent
   model, so how do I can redefine only the model and reuse the other
   classes and methods of the vendor?

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can:

```
use App\Entities\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\UserInterface;

class DoctrineUserAdapter implements UserInterface
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(User $user, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getBy($key, $value)
    {
        return $this->em->find('App\Entities\User', $value);
    }
}
```

You can inject EntityManagerInterface object as a second parameter, first parameter is a User model type from 'providers.user' in jwt.php configuration, why? Look at the code in `JWTAuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
/**
 * Register the bindings for the User provider.
 */
protected function registerUserProvider()
{
    $this->app['tymon.jwt.provider.user'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) {
        return $app->make($this->config('providers.user'), [$app->make($this->config('user'))]);
    });
}
```

My simple user model:

```
use DOctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
{
    use \LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Auth\Authenticatable;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     public $id;
}
```

2. You can do this in version 1.0.0. More about problem: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/343